# Wordpress / WooCommerce wp_localize_script to add php variable date to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m trying to add the coupon expiry information from WooCommerce to a countdown timer javascript file. In my WooCommerce child theme functions.php file I have created a variable to get the coupon expiry date:

`$expiry_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($coupon->expiry_date));`

If I echo this it is printing the correct date `echo $expiry_date;`

I’m trying to create a countdown timer based on this expiry date using the following javascript countdown timer:

```
// JavaScript Document
// https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

I have saved this script in my child theme, registered and enqueued it and am trying to pass the `$expiry_date` php variable via the Wordpress `wp_localize_script` method

```
function coupon_countdown_timer (){
    if ( is_cart()) {

        wp_register_script( 'coupon_countdown_timer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/countdown_timer/coupon_expiry.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
        
        wp_localize_script( 'coupon_countdown_timer', 'my_script_vars', array( 'expiry' => $expiry_date ));
        
        wp_enqueue_script( 'coupon_countdown_timer' );
        
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coupon_countdown_timer');
```

I should now be able to use `my_script_vars` and `expiry` from the `wp_localize_script` to add to my javascript file. But Im not sure what is the correct format. Every thing I have tried has returned either blank, "EXPIRED”, or NaN errors.

I have tried adding the php information into the javascript file these ways but nothing is working?

```
  var expiring = my_script_vars.expiry;
  var countDownDate = new Date(expiring).getTime();
```

and

```
var countDownDate = new Date(my_script_vars.expiry).getTime();
```

If I hardcode the date its working correctly.

```
  var countDownDate = new Date("2021-12-10 00:00:00").getTime();
```

If I add all the countdown timer javascript directly into functions.php and call it this way then it works correctly also.

```
var expiry = "<?php echo $expiry_date ?>";
var countDownDate = new Date(expiry).getTime();
```

But I just can’t get it to work if I try to enqueue the javascript. Any ideas how to format this correctly?

Comment: Please add a complete code for how you pass the coupon expiry date to localize the script.

Comment: @Bhautik I am printing html to output the expiry time on the cart page `<p id="demo"></p>` The script should pick this up to display the countdown timer.  `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";` But I cant get it to work. I think I am not adding the variable from `wp_localize_script` correctly.

Comment: I mean where is `$expiry_date` coming from? please add complete code in your question.

Comment: @Bhautik Oh ok I see, I'll post the function I am using:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to get this working, if anyone else gets stuck on this problem this may be a solution. First I created a new function that gets the coupon expiry date.

```
// Get the coupon expiry date and format
function woo_coupon_expiry_date () {
    
    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    
    foreach( $applied_coupons as $all_coupons ) {
        
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $all_coupons );
        $expiry_date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($coupon->expiry_date)); // change hyphens to slashes in date format for compatibility with Safari and IOS      
    }
    return ($expiry_date);  
}
```

I then called this function in another function that hooks into `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```
// Enqueue Scripts and localise for use with Javascript countdown timer
function coupon_countdown_timer (){

    wp_register_script( 'coupon_countdown_timer_js', plugins_url('/js/coupon_expiry.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' ), true );
    
    $coupon_expiry = woo_coupon_expiry_date ();
    
    wp_localize_script( 'coupon_countdown_timer_js', 'php_data', array( 'expiry' => $coupon_expiry ));
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'coupon_countdown_timer_js' );
        
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coupon_countdown_timer');
```

I could then call the php variable `$expiry_date` in the javascript countdown script this way:

```
  var expiring_date = php_data.expiry; 

  var countDownDate = new Date(expiring_date).getTime();
```